# selenium webdriver how to get text entered in iframe wysiwyg text area

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, wysiwyg

how to get text entered in iframe wysiwyg text area

```
// Enter text for Message field
ContactUs_Page.txt_keyInMessage().sendKeys(ColMessage);
```

ContactUs_Page.java

```
public static WebElement txt_keyInMessage() throws Exception{
    try{     
        WebElement iframeMsg= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'wysiwyg_frame')]"));        
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframeMsg);     
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);         
        element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));    
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw(e);
    }
    return element;
}
```

iframe html code

```
<iframe class="wysiwyg_frame" frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, contact_remarks" aria-describedby="cke_30" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
        <body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
            <p>
                hello, pls contact me once you received this message
                <br>
            </p>
        </body>
        </html>
</iframe>
```

eg. text entered here is

“hello, pls contact me once you received this message”

if in normal textbox, it can use `getAttribute(“value”)`

but in iframe wysiwyg text area, it don’t have `value` type

please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it is just the `text` of the `body` element inside an `iframe`:

```
WebElement iframeMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'wysiwyg_frame')]"));        
driver.switchTo().frame(iframeMsg);

WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
System.out.println(body.getText());
```